# Magento Multiple Website on Subdomains with All Checkouts on One Domain

Tags: magento, nginx

I have a magento site running on nginx with php-fcgi.

I have set up a main web site on the www. subdomain that works well with a SSL checkout.

I am trying to set up another magento website on the same installation on the "outlet." subdomain that will use the "www." SSL checkout.  I have the "outlet." subdomain site working and can add items to cart, but when I click to checkout the "www." checkout page (www.site.com/outlet/onestepcheckout/) returns a magento 404 not found error.  Interestingly, the cart shows the right count of items in the header of the 404 page, so it is recognizing the correct store/website, but is not finding the checkout page.

My nginx config file for the "www." subdomain has the following entry:

```
location ~ ^/outlet/ {
set $website_code outlet;
rewrite ^/outlet/(.*)$ /$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a subdirectory "outlet" and copied index.php to it.  Then edited the includes references in the new index.php to point up one directory.  The edit for the nginx config that worked is:

```
        location ~ ^/outlet/ {
                set $website_code outlet;
#               rewrite ^/outlet/(.*)$ /$1 last;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /outlet/index.php;
                index index.php;
                expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
#               expires        30d;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE  $website_code;
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE  website;
                include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
                fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

        }
```

Comment: If anybody has a cleaner solution, please share.